# Tuning capacitance-matching circuit

Tags: antenna, wireless, impedance-matching

I have designed an antenna for a WPT application. We already have a primary coil with a centered frequency of 13.56 MHz. We want to match the second coil at the same frequency and that's why we need to match the capacitance.

The circuit consists of:

[image]

We are working on optoelectronics in this project but one of our members left the team and we need to find a solution for the antenna. We thought that using a matching capacitance would be an "easy" solution for now.

[image]

My question is: we calculated the inductance of the antenna (around 0.7µH). We are using the following parameters for the antenna:

- wire width = 0.5 µm.
- wire spacing = 0.5 µm.
- number of loops = 5.

We calculated the theoretical capacitance that is supposed to be 31nF. However, we are designing this antenna for a flexible circuit using the substrate Pyralux 8535R from DuPont. I am worried that this may change the capacitance.

How would you tune the antenna supposing that the theoretical capacitance is right? Any ideas or guidance of how to do this?

Comment: There is no way that the tuning capacitor is 31 nF (maybe 31 pF).

Comment: For 0.7uH, at 13.56MHz, resonance is 197pF, or 0.200 nF.

Comment: I did the calculations wrong then! Which formula do you use for calculating the capacitance.

Comment: I used F_MHz = sqrt[ 25,330 / (L_uH * C_pF) ] and knowing you had 13.56MHz, that squared being about 170 = 25,330 / (L_uH * C_pF). And L_uH * C_pF now equals 25,330/170 ~~ 140. With L_uH = 0.7, now divide 140/0.7 to compute 200pF. Or use F = 1/(2pi*sqrt(L*C)).

Comment: alright thanks. Any tip about how to tune the antenna? like, how would you start and keep going?